# is there a way to automatically resize an image or any content based on the screen size in SWIFT?

Tags: swift, autolayout

I have been trying to find a way to resize an image based on the screen size programmatically without using storyboards?

Comment: imageView.frame = view.bounds. When you add imageView to main view you can add this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `swift add constraints programmatically`. This is very, very basic.

Here's a simple example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // create image view
        let imgView = UIImageView()
        
        imgView.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        // create image
        let img = UIImage(systemName: "person.fill")
        imgView.image = img
        
        // add imageView to view
        view.addSubview(imgView)
        
        // use auto-layout
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // constrain imageView width to view safe-area width
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            // aquare image view (1:1 ratio)
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor),
            // center vertically
            imgView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

---

**Edit** - second example... Top third, centered horizontally:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        // create image view
        let imgView = UIImageView()
        
        imgView.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        // create image
        let img = UIImage(systemName: "person.fill")
        imgView.image = img
        
        // add imageView to view
        view.addSubview(imgView)
        
        // use auto-layout
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // you want the image view at the top?
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            
            // one-third of the height of the view?
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0 / 3.0),
            
            // you want a aquare image view (1:1 ratio)?
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.heightAnchor),
            
            // you want it centered horizontally?
            imgView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            
        ])
        
    }
}
```

On iPhone 8:

[image]

On iPhone 12:

[image]

On 9.7" iPad Pro, landscape orientation:

[image]

Comment: what about if you want to position it based on screen size? for example say I was my logo to be in the upper third, in the middle of the screen (no storyboards). Thank you so much in advance :)

Comment: @Mohamad3736 - see the **Edit** to my answer. I added that as another example. But, really... this is ***fundamental*** auto-layout. Please read the documentation and work through a half-dozen or so tutorials.

Comment: That's great thank you but what I meant was, the same way you added a multiplier to the height to say that the height of this image should be 1/3 of the total view, is there a way to add a multiplier to the YAxis value so you can place the image above the center but not at the very top (I tried adding padding but it gets messed up with smaller sized screens). The reason I am asking is because I want to place two objects on-top of one another not just one. I tried looking at the documentation but their examples are too simple they don't help that much.